# reference range in different sheet with Indirect column and row

Tags: spreadsheet, google-spreadsheets

I'd like to reference a range in a separate worksheet using indirect relative row and column notation, something like this:
`=INDIRECT("'dataset'!R[0]C1:R[0]C4", FALSE)`
instead of
`=dataset!a1:d1`

is this possible? This formula doesn't work as is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I added your formula to a new spreadsheet. My spreadsheet settings are the following
[image: Spreadsheet Settings]

Locale: United States
*This is relevant because the locale determines the function parameter separator.*

[image: Google Sheets Screenshot: Before]
The address of the cell holding the formula is dataset!E1.
Formula `=INDIRECT("'dataset'!R[0]C1:R[0]C4", FALSE)`

Error:

> **Error**
> Function INDIRECT parameter 1 value is ''dataset'!R[0]C1:R[0]C4'. It is not a valid cell/range reference.

The apostrophes were the cause of the problem. Removing them, the formula works fine.
Formula: `=INDIRECT("dataset!R[0]C1:R[0]C4", FALSE)`

[image: Google Sheets Screenshot: After]

The apostrophes aren't required in INDIRECT.

Comment: I see now that this works, and I had tried that, it turns out that my issue is because I'm trying this in a data validation dropdown range. I get an error saying "please enter a valid range"

Comment: @fred Thanks for your comment. Please bear in mind that follow-up questions should be posted as new questions. If you like, you can ping me in a chatroom. For questions about Google Sheets, using a chatroom in [webapps.se] might be better.  This is relevant as most Google Sheets questions are off-topic here. I assume this one was not closed, as it looks to be centered on using a spreadsheet formula that overlaps across all the "standard" spreadsheet applications.